# Angular 10: Console shows my object as "unidentified" (pass data from parent to child)

Tags: javascript, angular, object, angular10

I am trying to pass data from the **parent** to the **child**. I get the correct output when I pass the string  **(data1)** from parent to child but when I try to display object **(data)** the console says it's unidentified and nothing is displayed on the screen.

**Parent Component:**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  data={
    name:'Charles',
    age:24,
    email:'charles@gmail.com'
  };
  data1 = "Charles";

}
```

```html
<app-contact [sendName] ="data"></app-contact>
```

**Child Component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() sendName;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.sendName);
  }

}
```

```html
<h1 class="text-center">Contact Form</h1>
<h3 class="pb-5">from the parent {{sendName.name}}</h3>
<h3 class="pb-5">from the parent {{sendName.age}}</h3>
```

please someone help me.
Thank you

Comment: Try `sendName?.name` and same for age in your template

Comment: It seems to be working here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufmhhm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: @iamentafaz thank you! yea I tried `sendName?.name` but I wanted to knw what was the problem with my code. The code works fine now. @eko thank you! yes the code works fine separately.

Comment: I also don't see any error in your code. Probably your code is trying to access the key before it's available in your child component.

Answer (score 0):

If your `data` (in parent component) variable has static value then your **child component** will be

```js
@Input() sendName;

ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.sendName);
}
```

If your `data` (in parent component) variable will assign from dynamic value then your **child component** will be

(Assume you have an API to call and update `sendName` variable on API response, but our child component is initialised without waiting the API response then we need to trigger `@Input()` to send updated data in child component )

```js
@Input() set sendName(value: any) {
    if(value){
        console.log(value);
        this.name = value
        // call any function from here
    }
}

name:any; // use this variable at anywhere

constructor(){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might be rendering the child, before setting the value in  data in parent

**in Child component** import Onchanges and get from **ngOnchanges()**

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input ,Onchanges} from '@angular/core';
    export class ContactComponent implements OnInit,Onchanges {
    
      @Input() sendName;   constructor() { }
    
      ngOnChanges() {
        console.log(this.sendName);   }
```